# How to prevent large decimal numbers being rounded off in javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal

Say I have a huge number: `999999999.9999999999;` 
When I try to store this number into a variable, in javascript, It stores the value `1000000000` into that variable.

How do I prevent this from rounding off and store the number as it is?

Comment: Not possible. You'll have to use a string instead of a number.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/ and https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js

Answer (score 1):

You could use third party lib to handle this, like `bignumber.js`, you can read more about `bignumber`  [here](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/)

> Please note that this is not possible with the javascript primitive types.

```js
let x = new BigNumber("999999999.9999999999");
console.log(x.toString());
//Add example
console.log(x.plus(23).toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/9.0.0/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```